# How can I step through instructions in IDA and know the current EIP?

Tags: ida, idapython, register

```
import idaapi
x=0
while x<10:
    idaapi.step_into()
    rv = idaapi.regval_t()
    idaapi.get_reg_val('EIP',rv)
    ea = rv.ival
    print hex(ea)
    x+=1
```

Hi. Here is a script to step-into 10 times.
I want to have an updated version of EIP value with idaapi.get_reg_val() API
If i run this code here is what i get.

```
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
0xffffffffffffffffL
```

Although the actual EIP value is valid all the time
I've also tried other path

```
while ea !=0x0040af75:
    idaapi.step_into()
    eip = GetRegValue('EIP')
    print eip
```

But then I just get pure error, the meaning of which is misterious to me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA 6.8\python\idc.py", line 7889, in GetRegValue
    assert res, "get_reg_val() failed, bogus register name ('%s') perhaps?" % name
AssertionError: get_reg_val() failed, bogus register name ('EIP') perhaps?
```

So it looks like either way it calls this low-level func - get_reg_val but can't use the string argument normaly.
Both theese functions get_reg_val and GetRegValue() work fine if not within a loop.
Help me

Comment: Since your output shows 64 bit values, maybe you're debugging a 64 bit program and should use `RIP` instead of `EIP` ?

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. But why does it work without a loop and also why I've got 32bit registers show in the window while I'm debugging the app in the regular mode? It doesn't make sence

Comment: Didn't help and the program is actually 32 bit

Comment: Just a wild guess: maybe in 'EIP' string some symbol happens to be non-ascii (e.g. due to an accidental keyboard layout change)?

Answer (score 5):

The valid answer to this problem is in the fact that python script and the debugger execution flows perform asynchornously. So each time we ask the debugger to do a step_into(), we also need to wait for this process to end.
This can be done by inserting GetDebuggerEvent(WFNE_SUSP, -1) after step_into

```
import idaapi

x=0
while x<10:
    idaapi.step_into()
    GetDebuggerEvent(WFNE_SUSP, -1)      
    rv = idaapi.regval_t()
    print idaapi.get_reg_val('EIP',rv)
    ea = rv.ival
    print hex(ea)
    x+=1
```

Comment: btw, idautils has a nice helper class that is more readable: cpu.Eip

Answer (score 1):

Have got the same error as in your other path, but with ESP register:

```
Python> GetRegValue('ESP')

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA 6.8\python\idc.py", line 7889, in GetRegValue
    assert res, "get_reg_val() failed, bogus register name ('%s') perhaps?" % name
AssertionError: get_reg_val() failed, bogus register name ('ESP') perhaps?
```

In my case the reason of this was running Static Analysis session. Just started Debugging, then Suspend manually or by BP, and GetRegVal() works fine.

```
Python> GetRegValue('ESP')
1232116
```