# Can I step through a binary with IDA (eval version), reading registers step-wise?

Tags: ida, debugging, disassemblers, register

I am new to disassembly, and I'm trying to understand how a 32 bit binary is operating. I have the evaluation (free) version, 32 bit (`Version 7.0.170920 macOS x86_64 (32-bit address size)`).

I'm used to debugging by stepping through a program, reading variables as necessary. I don't see an ability to do this in IDA, but I assume it must be there, and I'm simply missing it. (Having seen [this question about python](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/how-can-i-step-through-instructions-in-ida-and-know-the-current-eip) and [this question about ARM](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13520/stepping-through-arm-firmware-image#13529), surely this must be an option for 32 bit binaries...)

I'm also totally open to suggestions for a different disassembler than IDA, but I'm looking for something that is free - at least for an evaluation period of several days.

Comment: i dont know if mac version 7 does debugging the old free version 5.0 had debugging capabilities in x86 windows not sure if there was a free mac 5 version

Answer (score 2):

I own an IDA license, so I have no use for the free one. I don't know with complete certainty whether the freeware version does debugging, but here's a quote from the [freeware download page](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) about the limitations of the freeware version:

```
lacks support for many processors, file formats, debugging etc...
```

You might be out of luck trying to debug with the freeware version.

Comment: IDA's eval version indeed does not support debugging.